# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'function'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation, attributeerror

Can anyone please point out what's wrong in what I have implemented as below:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
    self.page = self.driver.get("http://mywebsite/form")
    self.page.search_trip(2, 2)

def search_trip(self, depart, arrival):
    departing  = Element(Locators.XPATH, "//select[@name='departing']/option[@value='%i']" %depart)
    returning  = Element(Locators.XPATH, "//select[@name='returning']/option[@value='%i']" %arrival)
    search     = Element(Locators.XPATH, "//input[@type='submit']")

    self.departing.click()  
    self.returning.click()
    self.search.submit()
```

Error code:

```
self.page.search_trip(2, 2)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'search_trip'
```

Comment: You should debug your code at least with print

Comment: Why are you assuming that `driver.get` returns something?

Answer (score 0):

`drive.get(url)` returns none! and `search_trip` is a method that belongs to the class and not self.page object (which is none here)!

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
    #driver.get() returns None
    self.driver.get("http://mywebsite/form")
    #search_trip is a method inside the class.
    self.search_trip(2, 2)

def search_trip(self, depart, arrival):
    departing  = Element(Locators.XPATH, "//select[@name='departing']/option[@value='%i']" %depart)
    returning  = Element(Locators.XPATH, "//select[@name='returning']/option[@value='%i']" %arrival)
    search     = Element(Locators.XPATH, "//input[@type='submit']")

    self.departing.click()  
    self.returning.click()
    self.search.submit()
```